# Find the highest value within multiple groups in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to find the highest salary within each decade for every given name. Below is my sample dataset and the line of code

```
| Bins  | Name | Salary |
|-------|------|--------|
| 1990s | Ron  | 8000   |
| 1990s | Ron  | 8500   |
| 2000s | Hary | 7000   |
| 1980s | Ron  | 6800   |
| 2010s | John | 10000  |
| 2010s | John | 21000  |

df.sort_values(by='Salary', ascending=False).groupby('Bins').reset_index()
```

But I keep getting error: "need to rewrap column in Series to apply key function"

My desired output should look like:

```
| Bins  | Name | Salary |
|-------|------|--------|
| 1980s | Ron  | 6800   |
| 1990s | Ron  | 8500   |
| 2000s | Hary | 7000   |
| 2010s | John | 21000  |
```

Comment: Let me know whether my solution works for you or need any fine-tuning.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df.groupby('Bins').max().reset_index()
```

Comment: I still get an error "Add key to exclusions"

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `['Bins', 'Name']` and use [`GroupBy.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) to get the highest value within the group (since you have sorted the values in descending order, the first entry within the group is the one with the highest value):

```
df.sort_values(by='Salary', ascending=False).groupby(['Bins', 'Name']).first().reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
    Bins  Name  Salary
0  1980s   Ron    6800
1  1990s   Ron    8500
2  2000s  Hary    7000
3  2010s  John   21000
```

Another way to do it is to group by `['Bins', 'Name']` and use [`GroupBy.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html)

```
df.groupby(['Bins', 'Name'], as_index=False)['Salary'].max()
```

Same result.